# Import tiled .TMX file into XNA?

Tags: xml, xna, tiled

Im in need of importing the TMX file which Tiled creates and using the map in visual studio, I seem to get an error when using xTiled so this won't be an option.

Comment: It's not quite clear what are you asking...

Comment: What's a TMX?  What error?  Any code to show?

Answer (score 0):

XTiled is just one of many options. Did you try any of the other ones?

https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/Support-for-TMX-maps#microsoft-xnanet